# How to add defer to a custom JS script in magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, requirejs

I need to add a custom script in my module and that script requires me to add defer in it. I have added the script in the requirejs-config.js file. But i am cannot see that script working. Although i am able to access objects from the custom script but some of the functionalities inside it are not working.

Please suggest how can i achieve the same.

Answer (score -1):

Use below extension. this extension better for you.

https://github.com/fballiano/magento2-defer-javascripts